# Combining two sets of data in XIRR

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a speadsheet with share transactions in one date/value pair of columns and dividends in another date/value pair. I would like to get a combined XIRR value for all of these transactions.

For for example my XIRR calculation for the share transactions is

```
=XIRR(J10:J40,A10:A40)
```

And my XIRR calculation for the dividend transactions is

```
=XIRR(N10:N40,L10:L40)
```

What is the best way to combine these to get a combined XIRR value?

Comment: I found two discussions that might help you:  https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/45364/irr-calculation-on-stock-with-dividends   ....  and ....    https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=225641

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output